# Making web app use alternate set of resources for testing

Tags: java, jetty, integration-testing, war

I am trying to get a web app (WAR) to use an alternate set of resources for integration testing. I am deploying my web app in jetty. How would I go about doing this?

To test it I use an external class where I create the jetty server and deploy the WAR in it. I need the WAR to use different resources for testing. I have a test folder with testing resources in it.

Also, I believe it may have something to do with the class loader of jetty and changing the location from where it looks at.

Thanks